# OpenMPI can't be compiled - possible collision?

Tags: c, linux, mpi, openmpi

I have installed openmpi by using this link http://lsi.ugr.es/~jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf
Howeere, I was getting error in compilation stage:

> /bin/sh: /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc: No such file or directory

Then I was suggested to install openmpi-devel, but then after installing , I get error which is described here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543045/openmpi-undefined-reference

The problem is that I don't know how to resolve this problem. I see that openmpi is installed with dnf search openmpi, but the command which mpicc is not working. When I installed manually from the first link it seems that I have some collision with commands in /home/$USER/.openmpi folder. Should I remove this folder and try something else?

Comment: You should add the following information to your question: Which distribution are you using? Did you install the distribution packages or compiled from source?

Comment: I am using Fedora 22. I got open-mpi with installation. But I couldn't find mpicc. That's why I compiled from source with instructions from http://lsi.ugr.es/~jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf.   I didn't know that I have installed open-mpi before mentioned problems appeared. No matter what I am doing I can't successfully compile first program.

Comment: 1. If you already have an openmpi installation, are you sure that you need another one? 2. If you do and if there is a collision with regard to the install directory (/home/$user/.openmpi), can you not simply use another directory by stating another prefix in your configure command as given in the manual you linked? (3. the original error (mpicc not existing) is likely because you have openmpi preinstalled but not the compiler wrappers; see also here: https://mmanoba.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/howto-openmpi-under-fedora15-and-sample-c-program/)

Comment: 1. I didn't check that I have openmpi installation, that's why I have installed openmpi. 2. I have removed /home/$user/.openmpi) from $PATH and now mpicc is in /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/ folder, but the error from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543045/openmpi-undefined-reference is present. 3. Now I realized that. Can I safely remove /$user/.openmpi/ folder where are the installation files (compiled from source)? I am confused how I have collision error if I have removed /$user/.openmpi/  from $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I just removed /home/$user/.openmpi/ folder and now I don't have collision.